An upper bound for $\sum_{|m| \le M} \min \left(N, \frac{1}{2 \|\alpha m\|}\right)$
I am currently studying Chapter 13 of Kowalski and Iwaniec's Analytic Number Theory, particularly the following inequality:
$$S := \sum_{|m| \le M} \min \left(N, \frac{1}{2 \|\alpha m\|}\right) \le (1 + 4Mq^{-1}) \left(N + \sum_{1 \le l \le q} q l^{-1}\right),$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the distance to the nearest integer. The assumptions provided are:

$q$ is an integer such that there exists an integer $a$ with $(a, q) = 1$ and $|\alpha - \frac{a}{q}| \le \frac{1}{q^2}$.
$m$ varies over a segment of length $\frac{q}{2}$.

I am trying to figure out how the the inequality for $S$ holds. Here are my attempts:

From assumptions 1 and 2, it appears that the points $\|\alpha m\|$ are distinct and spaced apart by at least $\frac{1}{2q}$.
Consequently, $\frac{1}{2 \|\alpha m\|}$ can be bounded by values of the form $q l^{-1}$.
If we consider a loose upper bound by assuming all terms contribute a maximum of $N$, we can denote this as $S'$. By multiplying $S'$ by the number of terms, which is bounded by $\frac{q}{2}$, we arrive at an upper bound. However, I find that the coefficient $1 + 4Mq^{-1}$ seems much smaller than $\frac{q}{2}$.
Finally, if we consider the case where all terms equal $N$, the right-hand side of $S$ would suggest a bound of $\frac{q}{2} \cdot N$, but I have not found a clear inequality that holds in this context.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to proceed to prove that the inequality holds for $S$ above.
